# how to split single integer value columns into n column?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server table table_name like:

```
col1   
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
.
.
.
N
```

i want output like below

```
col-1 | col-2 | col-3 | col-4 |col-5
-------------------------------
1     | 2     | 3     | 4     |5
6     | 7     | 8     | 9     |10
11    | 12    | 13    | 14    |15
```

how to get from this output  in sql-server query.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? If it is 2016, there is a STRING_SPLIT function.

Comment: Maybe table pivot will help here?

Comment: thanks, i am using SQL server 2012

Answer (score 6):

Another option is a Dynamic Pivot.

This will create N columns.

**Example**

```
Declare @nCols int  = 5

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Declare @nCols int = '+str(@nCols,5)+'
Select *
 From (
        Select RowNr = ((row_number() over (order by col1)-1)/@nCols)+1
              ,ColNr = concat(''col-'',isnull(nullif((row_number() over (order by col1))%@nCols,0),@nCols))
              ,Value = col1
         From YourTable
      ) A
 Pivot (max(Value) For ColNr in (' + Stuff((Select Top (@nCols) ','+QuoteName(concat('col-',Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)))) From  YourTable For XML Path('')) ,1,1,'') + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
--Print @SQL
```

**Returns**

[image]

**If @nCols = 3 , the Results are:**

[image]

> **EDIT a Fully Parameter Driven Version**

This version you can supply the

1. Number of Columns `@NbrCols` (same as above)
2. Source `@FromSrc`, which is the table name or a SQL String in () i.e. `(Select ...)`
3. The column name `@ColName` to Pivot `@ColName`
4. The colum prefix `@ColPrfx`  i.e. `'Col-'` or even `''`

---

```
Declare @NbrCols int  = 5
Declare @FromSrc varchar(max) = 'YourTable'  -- Or SQL '(Select col ...)'
Declare @ColName varchar(100) = 'col1'
Declare @ColPrfx varchar(100) = 'Col-'

Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Declare @NbrCols int = '+str(@NbrCols,5)+'
Select *
 From (
        Select Row = ((row_number() over (order by '+quotename(@ColName)+')-1)/@NbrCols)+1
              ,Col = concat('''+@ColPrfx+''',isnull(nullif((row_number() over (order by '+quotename(@ColName)+'))%@NbrCols,0),@NbrCols))
              ,Val = '+quotename(@ColName)+'
         From '+@FromSrc+' A1
      ) A
 Pivot (max(Val) For Col in (' + Stuff((Select Top (@NbrCols) ','+QuoteName(concat(@ColPrfx,Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)))) From master..spt_values For XML Path('')) ,1,1,'') + ') ) p'
Exec(@SQL);
--Print @SQL
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer yet, as the OP asked for n columns. got my vote.

Comment: I really like this answer, so +1, though I would suggest that `RowNr` could be simplified instead of using a window function
by modifying your query a little bit:
[dbfiddle.uk demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a9614cd9a4aab10ceb2d4a5beabd4ed2)
[rextester demo](http://rextester.com/YOXE25505), The execution plan is simpler without the window spool, though I haven't tested if there could be any significant performance difference when used with a larger dataset.

Comment: @SqlZim I was looking at your solution and was thinking the same.  Will make an update in a moment

Answer (score 4):

Using conditional aggregation based on dividing a [**`row_number()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx), and using [modulo **`%`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) for column placement:

test setup:

```
select n into dbo.numbers from (values 
  (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9),(10)
,(11),(12),(13),(14),(15),(16),(17),(18),(19),(20)
) t(n)
delete from dbo.numbers where n in (12,13,17);
```

query:

```
select 
    col1 = sum(case when rn%5=0 then n end)
  , col2 = sum(case when rn%5=1 then n end)
  , col3 = sum(case when rn%5=2 then n end)
  , col4 = sum(case when rn%5=3 then n end)
  , col5 = sum(case when rn%5=4 then n end)
from (
  select n, rn = row_number() over (order by n)-1
  from dbo.numbers
  ) t
group by rn/5;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/UHKY16981

returns:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 |
+------+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 | 3    | 4    | 5    |
|    6 |    7 | 8    | 9    | 10   |
|   11 |   14 | 15   | 16   | 18   |
|   19 |   20 | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+------+------+------+------+------+
```

---

The same concept but using `pivot()` instead of conditional aggregation returns the same results.

```
select 
    col1 = [0]
  , col2 = [1]
  , col3 = [2]
  , col4 = [3]
  , col5 = [4]
from (
  select n
    , rn  = (row_number() over (order by n)-1)%5
    , grp = (row_number() over (order by n)-1)/5
  from dbo.numbers
  ) t
pivot (sum(n) for rn in ([0],[1],[2],[3],[4])) p;
```

Comment: It's better then my answer. I started with conditional aggregation but somehow didn't quite got it right so I've chosen a different solution.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your table does not simply holds consecutive numbers from 1 to n (if it does, Gordon's answer is better),
here is one way to do it:

First, create and populate sample table (**Please** save is this step in your future questions)

```
SELECT TOP 100 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS col1
    INTO table_name
    FROM sys.objects s1       
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2 


DELETE
FROM table_name
WHERE col1 IN
(
    SELECT TOP 67 col1
    FROM table_name
    ORDER BY NEWID()
)
```

(table_name now contains 33 random numbers between 1 and 100)

Using a couple of common table expressions to get column number and row number:

```
;With Cols as
(
    SELECT  col1, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1) % 5 ColNumber
    FROM table_name
), RowsAndCols as
(
    SELECT col1, ColNumber, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ColNumber ORDER BY col1) As RowNumber
    FROM Cols
)
```

And the query:

```
SELECT c1.col1, c2.col1 As col2, c3.col1 As col3, c4.col1 As col4, c5.col1 As col5
FROM RowsAndCols c1
LEFT JOIN RowsAndCols c2 ON c1.RowNumber = c2.RowNumber AND c2.ColNumber = 2
LEFT JOIN RowsAndCols c3 ON c1.RowNumber = c3.RowNumber AND c3.ColNumber = 3
LEFT JOIN RowsAndCols c4 ON c1.RowNumber = c4.RowNumber AND c4.ColNumber = 4
LEFT JOIN RowsAndCols c5 ON c1.RowNumber = c5.RowNumber AND c5.ColNumber = 0
WHERE c1.ColNumber = 1
```

Note I've used left joins, so in case the number of rows is not a multiple of five you'll get nulls in the the last columns in the last row.

[See a live demo on rexteser.](http://rextester.com/GVRTA81654)

Comment: thanks for this query its working for me fine . thanks once again @Zohar Peled.

Comment: Glad to help :-). Now all you have to do is choose which answer you want to work with and mark it as accepted so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you want that output, you don't even need to start with a table:

```
with cte as (
      select 1 as col1, 2 as col2, 3 as col3, 4 as col4, 5 as col5
      union all
      select 5 + col1, 5 + col2, 5 + col3, 5 + col4, 5 + col5
      from cte
      where 5 + col1 <= 15
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Comment: Pls add Comma after Col4